# 2D Circular View/Background Wrapping SDL for Game

Tags: c++, sdl

In the games such as Defender (1980 arcade) and Defcon, the player can move/scroll in one direction infinitely because the level/terrain simply wraps over and over again(like if it was wrapped around the side of a cylinder).

I am more interested in the wrapping mechanics of Defcon which wrap(on the x-axis) and zoom the entire level. Here is a link to view the [game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCpVpIBqaJg).

To make images(such as a background) wrap is it a per-pixel approach? Is there a function? What methods are there to achieve the circular wrapping of a level?

Comment: Linear wrapping should do the trick.

Comment: Defcon's source code was released as part of Humble Bundle awhile back. Not sure if they still distribute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have used a repeating background image, I used two copies of the image side by side and scrolled the pair. When one gets to the edge of the screen, reposition it off the screen.