# Cylinder scrolling / wrap-around world using shaders?

Tags: shaders, libgdx, opengl-es2

I am making a 2D game using OpenGL ES 2.0 (libgdx), where the world will wrap-around itself on Y-axis.

Apart from implementing the ["modulo" method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/2d-circular-view-background-wrapping-sdl-for-game) in my rendering code, I'm wondering whether it's possible to render such a world using only shaders?

How would I go about handling the edge case in GLSL?

EDIT: Basically, I want to move this part of the code to the GPU, if possible.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17567/how-can-i-make-falling-away-3d-terrain-like-animal-crossing)? It's for 3D, but the principle is the same.